# What food options are available past security in Bangkok airport’s domestic section?

Tags: food-and-drink, bangkok, airport-terminals, bkk

I am flying in from Sweden through Suvarnabhumi onwards to Krabi. Having been in Thailand before, I know how long the lines can be, so I would like to clear immigration, customs and security as soon as possible.

Suvarnabhumi’s [website](https://www.bangkokairportonline.com/suvarnabhumi-airport-dining-guide-cafes-restaurants/) is kind of sketchy on the details as to what food options are available in the domestic part of the terminal. It seems there only something called City Garden, but doesn’t say what kind of venue it is (kiosk, fast food, breakfast, full service, etc).

What are my options? I will be arriving at around 6 AM, so a hearty meal might after the long leg might be in order.

**UPDATE:** According to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eOKtqjMYQvU) video of concourse A, B, C and D, it seems that there are plenty of outlets. Does anyone know if the video shows what is past the checkpoints?

Comment: https://www.bangkokairportonline.com/suvarnabhumi-airport-dining-guide-cafes-restaurants/

Comment: @mkennedy +1 make that an answer; spoiled for choice !

Comment: Done! I don't think it has all the info that Daniel wants so I tried to cover that. Hopefully someone else has been in the domestic terminal and has more info.

Comment: Another trick is to eat landside. You do everything as you say, up until check-in for the domestic flight (so you got rid of your large luggage). Then you walk back to the front of the building and go down to ground level (where the taxis are, not the basement). Still in the terminal you walk all the way to the west, until you arrive at the [food court](https://www.thai.lt/blog/414-food-court-at-suvarnabhumi-airport) where many of the (airline) staff eats. Cheap and easy, there are hearty meals for everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after coming home from the aforementioned trip, I can now confirm this:

There is a food court called ”Food Stop” that is located right after the special international-to-domestic security and immigration checkpoint. The outlets available at the time of writing are:

- McDonald’s*
- The Coffee Club*
- Krispy Kreem*
- 2 Ramen joints
- 3 Thai food joints
- A couple of fruit shake stands

It was kind of hidden, you have to make a U-turn after the checkpoint to find it. It was on the other side of the Boots store.

*) No affilliation or endorsement.

Answer (score 4):

Poking around, I came across [this website](https://www.bangkokairportonline.com/suvarnabhumi-airport-dining-guide-cafes-restaurants/). The main website is "Suvarnabhumi Airport: New Bangkok Airport Guide". The link goes to a long-style post about various restaurants and food stalls available on different levels and areas of the airport.

The page states there are several Asian eateries in the domestic end of the airport (Terminals A, B, and C) but lists and names City Garden only. It does list several restaurants and stalls in the Main terminal which I assume you would pass through from the international terminals (E, F, and G) to the domestic ones. Terminal D is along the Main Terminal and I couldn't determine if it handled domestic or international flights.

Comment: The site you’re referring to is the same where I got my initial information from. I apologize for not being more clear, I should have mentioned that. I will update my question to reflect this.

Comment: @Daniel I wondered about that. Thanks for updating the question.